# Deploying PERN stack application with AWS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, express

I developed a PERN (postgres, express, react, node) app that's running on my local machine and I want do deploy it using AWS. What is the "best" way to go about doing this if I want to be able to continuously deploy changes and handle the potential of scaling?

Answer (score 1):

For Database you can use RDS https://aws.amazon.com/rds/

For Hosting you can use EC2 Instance of your own https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/

You should dockerize your app

And Optionally can set up a continuous deployment pipeline using aws-codepipeline and aws-codedeploy . You can also use github actions for this purpose.

Comment: Are there advantages to setting up individual EC2 instances over using Elastic Beanstalk? I hope that question makes sense.

Comment: in EC2 you have complete control. That is an advantage for me because i like total control. but The appropriate answer is it depends on how much control do you want .

Comment: how does Docker fit in? I'm not clear on what it's used for.

Comment: Docker Containers handle All your installation and versioning mismatch issues while deploying. For example sometimes code works on local machine but not on ec2 or other server because of version mismatch of node or other dependencies. Docker helps to eliminate these problems.

Comment: @MohammadFaisal hi Mohammed what are the steps i should take (ie. the order of what to host first to last)

Comment: First and foremost you should have your database set-up on RDS
Then connect from. your local machine and develop your backend. 
Then host the backend on EC2